# Font scaling: Shrink all fontsizes locally

Tags: fontsize, scaling

I have a section at the end of my document that contains various elements that do not trivially react to writing `\small` in front of the section (e.g. `\printbibliography`, but also some custom commands).

Now I want to print this section in a smaller font. I tried wrapping elements into `\scalebox`, but this doesn't preserve the linewidth.

Solutions like the `scalefnt` or `relsize` package fail, since elements that explicitly use the font commands will still be unaffected.

Ideally I am looking for an environment, that redefines `\normalsize`, `small` etc to new values, proportional to the current values. It is acceptable for my purposes if this also changes the default definition.

As a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\newcommand{\somecommand}{\LARGE THIS IS LARGE \small this is small \normalsize\lipsum[1]}
\begin{document}

\section*{This should be typeset in document default sizes}

\somecommand 

\section*{This should be typeset in a smaller font without requiring knowledge of the internals of \texttt{\string\somecommand}}

%% what should be put here?
\somecommand

\section*{Scalebox doesn't cut it, if only because it introduces a box.}

\scalebox{0.5}{\somecommand}

\section*{If I could get this to fill the linewidth it would suffice as a temporary solution.}

\scalebox{0.5}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\somecommand}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled form]

Comment: Try \KOMAoptions{fontsize=8pt}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\newcommand{\somecommand}{\LARGE THIS IS LARGE \small this is small \normalsize\lipsum[1]}

\makeatletter
\let\zzfontsize\fontsize
\def\zz#1#2{{%
\def\fontsize##1##2{%
\@defaultunits\@tempdima##1pt\relax\@nnil
\@defaultunits\@tempdimb##1pt\relax\@nnil
\zzfontsize{#1\@tempdima}{#1\@tempdimb}}#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\section*{This should be typeset in document default sizes}

\somecommand 

\section*{This should be typeset in a smaller font without requiring knowledge of the internals of \texttt{\string\somecommand}}

%% what should be put here?
\zz{0.3}{\somecommand}

\section*{Scalebox doesn't cut it, if only because it introduces a box.}

\zz{0.5}{\somecommand}

\section*{If I could get this to fill the linewidth it would suffice as a temporary solution.}

\zz{2}{\somecommand}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It does just what I needed; Though I have read the recommedation to use `lmodern` instead of `fix-cm`. Do you happen to have any experience with that?

Comment: @kdb lmodern is fine (and the default if you use fontspec with lualatex or xelatex) but it is a different font set inspired by but not always identical to computer modern. fix-cm doesn't change the fonts at all at the normal sizes it just allows latex to scale rather than substitute a fixed size if you ask for non-standard sizes. So it's like asking if you prefer red or blue, it depends:-)